# Kafka Streams Internal Topic Naming

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

According to the documentation (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#internal-topics), internal topics follow the naming convention `<application.id>-<operatorName>-<suffix>`.

Some examples we have are:

```
testapplication-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000008-repartition  
testapplication-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000027-repartition
```

Does anyone know how the integer are determined?

Unfortunately our security requirements do not allow for us to create topics with our applications and need to be setup ahead of time.  I am trying to determine if these topic names will be consistent.

Comment: Why did you change your question? This makes existing answers void... You should have rather asked a new question.

Comment: It an implementation detail and you should not rely how those name are generated. Internally, it's just a counter that is increase each time a new name is generated.

Comment: If this is an issue, you can also name certain operators/stores to set the names in your code.

Comment: How do you do that? We are using the DSL api and see no way for the reduce operation to name the topic.  If you can write an answer describing that it would be great!

Comment: All stateful operator have overload to pass in optional argument like `Materialized` or `Joined` that allow to specify names: If you could read the docs, that would be great: https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedKStream.html#aggregate-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-

Comment: Sorry... couldn't resist... More details https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-182%3A+Reduce+Streams+DSL+overloads+and+allow+easier+use+of+custom+storage+engines and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-372%3A+Naming+Repartition+Topics+for+Joins+and+Grouping

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, yes I see the reduce method can take in a Materialized object as the second argument.  But isnt that for the file based state store and not a new kafka topic?

Comment: It's also used the name the changelog topic... Please read the docs... JavaDocs state: "The changelog topic will be named "${applicationId}-${storeName}-changelog", where "applicationId" is user-specified in StreamsConfig via parameter APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "storeName" is the provide store name defined in Materialized, and "-changelog" is a fixed suffix. You can retrieve all generated internal topic names via Topology.describe()."

Comment: I read the docs! I do not want to create a new state store and have that on my file system just so I can name a topic.

Comment: If you do an aggregation, you always need a store. Note, that you can replace the default RocksDB store with an in-memory-store via `Materialized.as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("yourCustomName"))`

Answer (score 2):

Usually the intermediate topic names are constructed with following convention:

```
<ApplicationId>-<operator name>-<suffix>
```

Suffix value can be either "changelog" or "repartition"

Based on the operator, it uses one of the suffix. Here is an example:

**testapplication-aggregate-repartition**

**testapplication-aggregate-changelog**

Comment: So we have some that are like testapplication-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000008-repartition and testapplication-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000027-repartition.  Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: These numbers represent the processor node along  -KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE. Topology is built with many processor node and each node has unique ID. so default state-store naming convention uses those name.

Comment: By looking at those topic names, can I infer the sequence of stream processing?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question about the integer, that's what I found in docs:

> The **number** is a globally incrementing number that represents the
> operator’s order in the topology. The generated number is prefixed
> with a varying number of “0”s to create a string that is consistently
> 10 characters long.

This is quite important aspect of kafka streams DSL and can lead to some problems if you change a topology. It's a good practice to name your stateful operator.

More information you can find in [dsl-topology-naming](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-topology-naming.html#changing-names) article

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these commands to set ACL for Streams internal topics. I believe they are introduced as part of Kafka v2.x.x ([confluent doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html#required-acl-setting-for-secure-kafka-clusters))

```
   # Allow Streams to manage its own internal topics and consumer groups:
   bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation All --resource- 
   pattern-type prefixed --topic team1-streams-app1 --group team1-streams-app1
```

So you just need to know the steams application.id, which is the prefix of all internal topics.

I believe as you will give permission ALL, that would allow their creation as well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about topic names being consistent, in my experience, they have been consistent between executions of the application, however, if you modify the order of, add, or delete any joins or reduces within your logic, the topic names may change.

Answer (score -1):

Integers are internally generated.

You can find it documented here:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/index.html

Under groupBy method descriptions it says:

> Because a new key is selected, an internal repartitioning topic will be created in Kafka. This topic will be named "${applicationId}-**XXX**-repartition", where "applicationId" is user-specified in StreamsConfig via parameter APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, **"XXX" is an internally generated name**, and "-repartition" is a fixed suffix. You can retrieve all generated internal topic names via Topology.describe().

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The integers are internal counters and considered an implementation detail.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax you are correct.  I understand it is an implementation detail.  Unfortunately our security requirements do not allow for us to create topics with our applications and need to be setup ahead of time.  I am trying to determine if these topic names will be consistent.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax he edited original question in which he didn't ask for implementation details

Comment: @Chris As long as you don't change the topology, the names will not change. you can figure out the name via `Topology#describe()`.